# Sugar Minting Multiple?

Tags: mint, sugar

I have deployed my collection using Sugar.  I am able to use sugar mint, to mint one. In the old CM2 CLI you could do mint multiple # Is this no longer possible using the new interface ?

Comment: please elaborate the question with a description of how you used to be able to do this with the old interface, what you've tried with the new one and why you think the feature is not available

Answer (score 1):

`sugar mint` has the following flag:

```
    -n, --number <NUMBER>
            Amount of NFTs to be minted in bulk
```

So you can still mint multiple:

```
sugar mint --candy-machine ... --number 10
```

Btw, just run commands with `--help` to see the available options.